# How to set downloads history to be cleaned on exit in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

The title is self explanatory.
How do you set Chrome to clean the downloads history upon exit (on Mac)?

Answer (score 2):

or you can open chrome in "[incognito](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95464)" everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Use the extension, Click&Clean to do this

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ghgabhipcejejjmhhchfonmamedcbeod?hl=en

Comment: It's not working on Mac (or Linux) :(

Comment: Oh sorry, I've only tried it on windows, but to be honest, chrome on mac and linux isn't really all that, I would stay with the default Safari and Firefox on them.